# Find position of item in list using Binary Search

Tags: string, list, recursion, mergesort

The question is:

> Given a list of String, find a specific string in the list and return
>   its index in the ordered list of String sorted by mergesort. There are
>   two cases:
>
> 1. The string is in the list, return the index it should be in, in the ordered list.
> 2. The String is NOT in the list, return the index it is supposed to be in, in the ordered list.

Here is my my code, I assume that the given list is already ordered.

For 2nd case, how do I use mergesort to find the supposed index? I would appreciate some clues.

I was thinking to get a copy of the original list first, sort it, and get the index of the string in the copy list. Here I got stuck... do I use mergesort again to get the index of non-existing string in the copy list?

```java
public static int BSearch(List<String> s, String a) {

    int size = s.size();
    int half = size / 2;
    int index = 0;
    // base case?

    if (half == 0) {

        if (s.get(half) == a) {
            return index;
        } else {
            return index + 1;
        }
    }

    // with String a
    if (s.contains(a)) {
        // on the right
        if (s.indexOf(s) > half) {
            List<String> rightHalf = s.subList(half + 1, size);
            index += half;
            return BSearch(rightHalf, a);

        } else {
            // one the left
            List<String> leftHalf = s.subList(0, half - 1);
            index += half;
            return BSearch(leftHalf, a);
        }
    }
    return index;
```

}

When I run this code, the index is not updated. I wonder what is wrong here. I only get `0` or `1` when I test the code even with the string in the list.

Comment: This line `if (s.contains(a))` kinda defeats the purpose of doing a binary search...

Comment: because there are two cases in the question, i was thinking about has string in the list first, then thinking about the string not in the list

Comment: If you do the binary search correctly, you just need one code to determine where the string will be

Answer (score 2):

Your code only returns `0` or `1` because you don't keep track of your index for each recursive call, instead of resetting to `0` each time.  Also, to find where the non-existent element should be, consider the list `{0,2,3,5,6}`. If we were to run a binary search to look for `4` here, it should stop at the index where element `5` is.  Hope that's enough to get you started!

Comment: i deal with string. from a-z.  i understand what u mean,